# Vanilla JS Vigenere Cypher Decoder

Tags: javascript, html, css, vigenere-cipher

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChimeraZen/qfLgqqux/)

**Questions**

1. Supposedly there's an issue with using ^ in a regex statement. Is that always the case or is it acceptable to use as I have here?
2. Should I include a validation to ensure there are no empty fields or would that be extraneous?
3. Would my code be considered insecure?

```js
/**
* Name:        Vigenere Cypher Decoder
* Description: A vanilla JS application to decode a Vigenere Cypher with a known key
* @package     Chimera Apps
* @version     1.0.0
* @author      Chimera.Zen
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017, Chimera.Zen
* @link        https://github.com/ChimeraZen/Vigenere-Cypher
* @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

"use strict";
var cypherAlphabet,
    cypherAlphabetChar,     // Each character of the cypher alphabet
    cypherKey,
    cypherKeyChar,          // Each character of the cypher key
    cypherLength,
    decryptedAlphabet,      // Each character as it's decrypted
    encryptedString,
    encryptedStringChar,    // Each character of the encryptiong string
    encryptedLength,
    encryptedAlphabet = [], // An array of the reorganized alphabet to be used on encryptedStringChar
    i,
    ii,
    results;                // Div#results

// Decode encryption using cypher key and encrypted text
function decryptingCypher(a, b) {
  encryptedStringChar = encryptedString.substring(a + 1, a);
  decryptedAlphabet   = encryptedAlphabet[b].toString().indexOf(encryptedStringChar);
  // Display results in div#results
  results.innerHTML  += cypherAlphabet.substring(decryptedAlphabet + 1, decryptedAlphabet);
}

// Applies the cypher alphabet to each character of encrypted string
function startDecryptingCypher() {
  encryptedLength = encryptedString.length;
  for (i = 0; i < encryptedLength; i++) {
    if (ii < cypherLength) {
      decryptingCypher(i, ii);
      ii++;
    } else {
      ii = 0;
      decryptingCypher(i, ii);
      ii++;
    }
  }
}

// Creates the encoded alphabet based off of the cypher key and its length
function createEncryptedAlphabet() {
  for (i = 0; i < cypherLength; i++) {
    cypherKeyChar = cypherKey.substr(i, 1);
    for (ii = 0; ii < 26; ii++) {
      cypherAlphabetChar = cypherAlphabet.substr(ii, 1);
      if (cypherKeyChar === cypherAlphabetChar) {
        encryptedAlphabet[i] = cypherAlphabet.substring(cypherAlphabet.indexOf(cypherKeyChar)) + cypherAlphabet.substring(parseInt('-' + cypherAlphabet.indexOf(cypherKeyChar), 10), ii);
      }
    }
  }
  startDecryptingCypher();
}

// Prep encrypted string - remove spaces, special characters and new lines
function prepEncryptedString(encryptedString) {
  return encryptedString.replace(/([^A-Za-z])|(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/gi, "");
}

// Set Demo parameters
function demoSwitch() {
  if (document.getElementById("demo").checked === true){
    document.getElementById("cypherAlphabet").value   = "KRYPTOSABCDEFGHIJLMNQUVWXZ";
    document.getElementById("cypherKey").value        = "PALIMPSEST";
    document.getElementById("encryptedString").value  = "EMUFPHZLRFAXYUSDJKZLDKRNSHGNFIVJYQTQUXQBQVYUVLLTREVJYQTMKYRDMFD";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cypherAlphabet").value   = "";
    document.getElementById("cypherKey").value        = "";
    document.getElementById("encryptedString").value  = "";
  }
}

// Initialize the parameters
function decryptCypher() {
  cypherAlphabet    = prepEncryptedString(document.getElementById("cypherAlphabet").value);
  cypherKey         = prepEncryptedString(document.getElementById("cypherKey").value);
  encryptedString   = prepEncryptedString(document.getElementById("encryptedString").value);
  cypherLength      = cypherKey.length;
  encryptedLength   = encryptedString.length;
  results           = document.getElementById("results");
  results.innerHTML = "";
  createEncryptedAlphabet();
}
```

```css
.vigenere-cypher {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vigenere-cypher h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.vigenere-cypher .params {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 45%;
  max-width: 600px
}
.vigenere-cypher input[type=checkbox] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.vigenere-cypher input[type=text] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 1px 2px 0 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
.vigenere-cypher textarea {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
.vigenere-cypher button {
  height: 30px;
}
.vigenere-cypher #results {
  width: 45%;
  height: 221px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
  background: #FFF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vigenere-cypher">
      <h1>
        Vigenere Cypher Decoder
      </h1>
      <div class="params">
        <label>Enable Demo<input id="demo" type="checkbox" value="value" onclick="demoSwitch()"></label>
        <input id="cypherAlphabet" type="text" placeholder="Cypher Alphabet" value="" />
        <input id="cypherKey"type="text" placeholder="Cypher Key" value="" />
        <textarea id="encryptedString" placeholder="Text to decode"></textarea>
        <button onclick="decryptCypher();">DECRYPT CYPHER</button>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have a source for `there's an issue with using ^ in regex`? it's a special char so if you're trying to match it you have to escape it, otherwise i'm not sure what you could be referring to ...? (ps... followed you on gh)

Comment: Thanks :). It's primarily because of an error that popped up in JSlint "insecure ^" so I altered the config entry to make JSlint ignore it. Ignoring without knowing why is dangerous in my experience lol but from what I understand, it's just JSlint being overly sensitive

Comment: I [see what you mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4109214/1444609). I think your regex is fine.